# Distributed Cache error in uls logs Unexpected error in Decrypt - Exception 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

Tags: 2016, asp.net, distributedcache, sharepoint-server

Hi In WFE servers of SharePoint 2016 in uls logs there are many DCache errors like below and server performance is high

```
w3wp.exe (0x0918)   0x2C48  SharePoint Foundation   DistributedCache    aa6e5   Unexpected  
Unexpected error in Decrypt - Exception 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.DepadBlock(Byte[] block, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()     at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)     at System.IO.Stream.Close()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCacheUtils.Transform(Byte[] buffer, ICryptoTransform transformer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCacheUtils.Transform(Byte[] secretKey, Byte[] buffer, 
Boolean encrypt)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCacheUtils.Decrypt(Byte[] secretKey, Byte[] buffer)'.  
e942a99e-a39e-708e-14d1-17caed54aa6a

http://intranet.xxx/vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.rtol.css
```

below error in event viewer:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String name, String value)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://intranet.xxxx/PublishingImages/Smallimg/3.jpg
```